# Preact PWA, configure maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes to change this limit

Tags: caching, service-worker, filesize, preact

I'm creating a PWA using the Preact Cli.

When compiling I get the warning:

> /bundle.js is 2.15 MB, and won't be precached. Configure
> *maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes* to change this limit.

Since Preact CLI generates a service worker when building, to customize the service worker,
I've created a custom "sw.js" that uses the Preact CLI high-level API.

The question is how to use this API to change the "*maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes*" (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a situation where you need to be careful that you're not precaching large items accidentally, but if you need to up the limit, you can use your `preact.config.js` file to do so. All of this is done with WorkBox's `InjectManifest` plugin, so editing the service worker itself would do nothing.

preact.config.js

```js
export default {
    webpack(config, env, helpers, options) {
        const manifestPlugin = helpers.getPluginsByName(config, 'InjectManifest')[0];
        if (manifestPlugin) {
            manifestPlugin.plugin.config.maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // or however much you need. This is 5mb.
        } 
    }
}
```